# Can I change a JSON key from string value to an array of value in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi I would like to check if there's a way to convert one of my JSON property's value from string to an array of string.

What I have:

```
const testJSON = {
  "name": "Albert"
}
```

What I want:

```
const testJSON = {
  "name": ["Albert"]
}
```

Many thanks for any help and direction I could explore!

Comment: `testJSON.name = [testJSON.name]` ...?

Comment: [You are working with JavaScript, not JSON.](https://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: @Quentin thank you for the article, I will read it up! I am still learning and do not have much background knowledge, thanks for correcting my mistake!!

Comment: @Alim Did you get a chance to look into the answer I added ? I hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give a try to this dynamic solution with the help of [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method.

```js
const testJSON = {
  "name": "Albert"
};

Object.keys(testJSON).forEach(key => {
    testJSON[key] = [testJSON[key]]
});

console.log(testJSON);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign new value which can be string or array to json property.

For example:

```js
const testJSON = {
  "name": "Albert"
}

// new array which we will assign to previous array property
const newArray = ["Albert", "John"];

// assigning new array to old json property
testJSON.name = newArray;
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't think so, you only do maybe like the comment above

```
 {name: [testJSON.name]}
```

if you have array, u can do .map for it